# Shared iAD banner but only on certain views

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

I have correctly implemented a shared iAd banner in the appDelegate and in certain views(which are adbanner delegates) it appears correctly. How ever in the views where I dont show the banner (so they are not adbanner delegates) when the appdelegate fails to retrieve a Banner since there is no current delegate and no current didFailToRecieveAdWithError method the console shows an error saying that efectively there is no method to recieve the error. Do i need to make the appDelegate also the AdBannerDelegate and put those methods inside?

In appDelegate:

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.
_UIiAD = [[ADBannerView alloc]init];
return YES;
}
```

in ViewController where I want a Banner:

```
- (CrystalAppDelegate *)appDelegate
{
     return (CrystalAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    _UIiAD = [[self appDelegate] UIiAD];
    _UIiAD.delegate = self;

    [_UIiAD setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 518, 320, 50)];
    [self.view addSubview:_UIiAD];
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    NSLog(@"Banner did Load");
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [_UIiAD setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Banner did not Load");
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [_UIiAD setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    _UIiAD.delegate = nil;
    _UIiAD = nil;
    [_UIiAD removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Problem is when i am in a view that doesnt have a banner i dont have these methods so when the appDelegate doesnt retrieve a iAdBanner there is no method to revieve the error.

Comment: Append your code plz. Where do you setDelegate: for the iAd banner?

Comment: theres my code @trick14